# How do I maintain the backslash when converting to json String using Json Format of Protobuf?

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I have to use gRPC.

I was converting the object I received into json string, and the following problem occurred

example proto

```
hash: "v\016\177\350\207y\225wM\335]1(Z\266\305\376\027\310_v\321\016Q\v\332\030\303^\032|\375"
```

but, However, if I convert using Protobuf's util JsonFormat, I get the following results

```
 "hash": "dg5/6Id5lXdN3V0xKFq2xf4XyF920Q5RC9oYw14afP0="
```

I want to get this back to its original form, is there a way to write another library or decode it in reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about the format, basically; these are just two ways of representing the same data. The second version is base-64, and decodes to the bytes:

```
76-0E-7F-E8-87-79-95-77-4D-DD-5D-31-28-5A-B6-C5-FE-17-C8-5F-76-D1-0E-51-0B-DA-18-C3-5E-1A-7C-FD
```

The first version is C-literal style with octal escapes; `v` is ASCII 118, aka hex 0x76; `\016` is escaped octal for decimal 14, aka hex 0x0E; `\177` is escaped octal for decimal 127, aka hex 0x7F - and so on. Most languages have a base-64 encode/decode; the C-literal style with octal escape sequences is ... more niche, and you might need to write your own decoder for that. Depending on where the first string came from, it is worth noting that protobuf (at least the schema variant) also allows fixed-width unicode escapes, via `\uNNNN` and `\UNNNNNNNN`, IIRC. And note: the octal in .proto schemas can short-circuit: `\12n` means the same as `\012n` - at most 3 digits are taken, but if a non-digit character is encountered, it is still valid as a shorter form.

Comment: I'm trying to find the original string in reverse.

I understand how to convert Base64 back to byte code.(76-0E-7F-E8-87...)


Is there any way to convert this byte code back to C literal (v\016\177\350...)?

Comment: @PaperFrog sure, but not usually inbuilt; here's a version I wrote previously (for C#, but the intent should be obvious): https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/3b97d78b7e6ace7d53af7ddfb243417f611f0c9e/src/protobuf-net.Reflection/TokenExtensions.cs#L229-L258